# R shiny - download uiOutput as PDF

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am trying to create a R markdown file that works with the downloadHandler in my shiny app. In the r markdown I just need a simple uiOutput. Below is how I attempted to pass it into the markdown file.

**In server:**

```
output$myOutput <- renderUI({
    ... # the output that needs to be printed 
})

output$downloadChart <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      params <- list(report = output$myOutput)
      
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file, params = params, envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    }
)
```

**report.Rmd**

````
---
title: "report"
output: pdf_document
params:
  report: NA
---

```{r}
params$report```
````

When the code above is used, a HTML file is downloaded. I don't really understand why is this so since I already specified PDF. Is this not the right way to produce a downloadable file? I'm very new to R shiny. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's impossible to read the **output** object in Shiny. What is your chart?